# Indentation error in elif python 3.5

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.5 idle.
I am getting an indentation error while using elif function.
This is the code that I've entered:

```
>>> num = 7

>>> if num == 5:

    print("number is 5")

... elif num == 11:

  File "<stdin>", line 2

    elif num == 11:
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Have you done any research on how such structures work? Or read the error message?

Comment: You need to write some lines of code when `num == 5` before adding `elif`

Comment: Perhaps show some patience to us, by reading the How To Ask page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write some code after your `elif`. For example:

```
>>> num = 7
>>> if num == 5:
...     print("Number is 5")
... elif num == 11:
...     print("Number is 11")
...
>>> if num == 5:
...     print("Number is 5")
... elif num == 11:
...     print("Number is 11")
... elif num == 7:
...     print("Number is 7")
...
Number is 7
>>>
```

This happens when you press enter after `elif num == 11:`

```
>>> if num == 5:
...     print("Number is 5")
... elif num == 11:
...
  File "<stdin>", line 4

    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
>>>
```

If you don't want to do anything for some reason in that case use `pass`

```
>>> num = 11
>>> if num == 5:
...     print("Number is 5")
... elif num == 11:
...     pass
... elif num == 7:
...     print("Number is 7")
...
>>>
```